# Evaluating language identification methods

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, evaluation, n-gram

Part of my thesis work is to evaluate number of language detection methods that are already available and then finally implement one them. 
For this I have chosen the following methods,

1. N-Gram-Based Text Categorization by Cavnar and Trenkle
2. Statistical Identification of Language by Ted Dunning
3. Using compression-based language models for text categorization by Teahan and Harper
4. Character Set Detection
5. A composite approach to language/encoding detection

I have to first evaluate the methods and preferably present a table with accuracy for each of these methods. My question is that in order to find the accuracy of each of these methods, do I need to go ahead a build the language models using training data, then test them and record the accuracy or is there any other approach that I can follow here. Though most of the researches already include these accuracy tables, I am not sure if it's accepted in my education to simply grab it and present in the report.

Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Seems like that would be a question for your thesis adviser.

Comment: A meta-analysis (compiling and summarizing previous research) is acceptable research, but probably not in this case sufficient for a Master's. Depends a lot on your subject, too. Is this industrial processing, computer science, machine learning, computational linguistics, or what?

Comment: If you say "evaluate, then build", how would you evaluate something you haven't implemented, other than just by reporting previous results, and reasoning (vaguely) about strengths and weaknesses?

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest asking your thesis advisor. Implementing all of them will be a lot of work, and it is very difficult to really compare them without being able to test them. If I remember correctly the last three have not been well evaluated in the literature, so it would be difficult to compare their results. I have implemented (and evaluated) only the first one of those myself. One big question is also how big a part of your thesis this LI evaluation and implementation is?

Comment: LI evaluation and implementation is one of the six research questions I have in my thesis. The bachelor's degree I am doing is mathematics and applications, the whole study focused a lot on algorithms,data structures and different programming languages. So for in my thesis I have done the following, analysing their workflow

Comment: Continuation.. 1.Analysing the workflow at a LSP, 2.Analysing a open translation API, 3.Implementing a server for the LSP using the API, 4.Adding LI to the server. So implementing LI is not so difficult, I am just looking for some ways to show the reason I chose a method.